# Auto Complete Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio

When typing in Visual Studio, normally to autocomplete I hit enter twice and I am returned to the line below where I am actively typing. However when I type Marg  then am put into the quotes, type a number then hit enter. The last quote is taken to the next line. Is there a better way to auto complete Margin="5" ? Thanks!

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
Width="250" 
Height="20" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
Margin="5" 
</Grid>
```

Comment: For me is not clear what you exactly want and how you tried to solve this problem by yourself.

Comment: This is just the way auto-complete works for XAML. It is not a major issue, merely one press of the > button. Suck it up and move on I'd say...

Comment: @MoonKnight is there a hotkey for the `>` character?

Comment: I'm just talking about the right arrow key. You and up with `Margin="5<cursor here>"`, just press the right arrow key, your done...

Comment: I can use the arrow keys, just it seemed odd to me that Visual Studio was inconsistent in its auto complete function.

Comment: @tym32167 I tried every key combination I could find online and in the options of visual studio, I then looked up short cuts for visual studio, then tried posting to reddit, the microsoft forum and then stack overflow. Kinda new to this whole thing, if you have any suggestions for anything else I should have done I am happy to hear it.

Comment: @MoonKnight I was joking :-)

Comment: @james the solution is to type the missing character if autocomplete doesn't do it for you. What's the issue here?

Comment: @JayGould Really just trying to be efficient. Also as this is really my first interaction with Visual Studio I thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: This is the way VS behaves... Move on and good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about IDE behavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Visual Studio does the best it can to autocomplete your input. You have to realize that there are two different cases:

1. An enumeration is expected between the quotes, e.g. you type

   ```
   TextA
   ```

   and then press Enter. VS autocompletes this to

   ```
   TextAlignment=""
   ```

   and puts the cursor between the quotes. You can choose a valid value from an enumeration. Lets say you press C for Center. Visual Studio puts Center between the quotes.

   ```
   TextAlignment="Center"
   ```

   Because it's a value from an enumeration, VS knows that you're done with entering something between the quotes and automatically puts the cursor one column ahead just behind the quotes. If you press Enter now, you get a new line.
2. A free value is expected between the quotes, e.g.

   ```
   Margin="10"
   ```

   Lets say you just entered the 10. Now VS can not know if you're done with entering a value or if you want to want to key in more digits. VS can not move the cursor outside the quotes like it does with the enums. You have to leave the quotes by pressing the right arrow yourself.

Comment: I realize your not suppose to say thanks, but either way this is a clear and understandable answer that clarifies the logic that is taken place when using Visual Studio. Appreciate it.